# lambda function produce this 3 with one parameter,

Tags: python

```
>>> b = lambda x, y = 2: x + y
>>> b( 1 )

3
```

I can't figure out how this function produces 3

Comment: `y` is default parameter which is initialized to `2`. *P.s see the statement `y = 2`*

Comment: You can read about [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) in the official tutorial. The examples there use `def` functions, but it works the same with `lambda`s.

Comment: You passed it a value of `1` for `x`, it used the default value of `2` for `y`, and `1 + 2` is `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b is equivalent to

```
def b(x, y=2):
    return x+y
```

Then I think you could understand why b(1) is 3

Answer (score 0):

That's because a default value is set to `y`

Let's see with demo:

- with no default value

  ```
  >>b = lambda x, y: x + y
  >>b()
  TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
  >>b(1)
  TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
  >>b(1,2)
  3
  ```
- With default value in `y`

  ```
  >>b = lambda x, y=1: x + y
  >>b()
  TypeError: <lambda>() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
  >>b(1)
  2
  >>b(1,2)
  3
  ```
- With two default value

  ```
  >>b = lambda x=2, y=1: x + y
  >>b()
  3
  >>b(1)
  2 
  >>b(2,2)
  4
  ```